# Is there an ID for XCM message?

Tags: xcm

I want to do some logging related to xcm messages and I need an ID for the message.
If there is no ID for XCM, is there a proper way to generate the ID for the message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no inbuilt ID for an XCM message.

If there were then it would probably better belong to the transport mechanism (e.g. XCMP, UMP, DMP, bridge) rather than XCM which is merely the message *format*. Unfortunately even if those transport mechanisms did provide a unique identifier it would not work for messages where the conceptual "destination" is not the *immediate* destination of the message (e.g. `ReserveAssetTransfer` or `ExportMessage`). In these cases what is actually happening is that you are sending a message to an (initial) destination which is then executing it and in doing so sending one or more further messages to one or more further destinations. This may even happen multiple times, leading to a cascade of messages actually being sent. It becomes completely undefined - to XCM - what these messages' relationship to the originally sent message is: is it notionally the *same* message just being routed a further step (and thus should perhaps have the same ID)? A *reply* or error report? A new message containing information or an instruction for a third-party?

So we need something more sophisticated than a mere unique ID for messages on a single endpoint-pair for the ID to be generally useful. And indeed, in XCM v3 something more sophisticated exists to help with tracking an XCM message as its effects are felt between chains:

1. Message Hash. This is returned as part of sending an XCM (through the `SendXcm` trait) and can be used to identify the message through its context at the destination point. This has two main limitations in utility:

- A message with exactly the same content would have the same hash. This can be worked around by introducing an instruction into the message which does nothing but ensure it has a unique hash, (e.g. `SetErrorHandler(Xcm(vec![Trap(<ID>)]))` in the last position).
- Any message which relies on XCM instructions for effecting a multi-hop route (e.g. using `ReserveAssetTransfer` or `ExportMessage` in v3) won't work since the message contents are necessarily different depending on which leg of the journey it is on.

2. Topics. The Topic is a register in the XCVM which is passed to any external functions. It may be set to any value using the `SetTopic` instruction. This allows a sender to craft a message which carries with it an ID tag. The nice thing about the Topic is that when combined with the message *origin*, it can be made into a secure, universally-unique identifier. It can also be used inside of internal message fragments, carrying the *conceptual* identity of a message even when the message gets edited as it moves through different hops on its journey.

Comment: Would be nice if the sending chain emitted the message hash as an event (by default). That would allow message hash to be followable by external block explorers. Even if a topic is set, an external block explorer will not be able to follow the message unless the source chain emits an event with the sent topic in it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the upcoming XCM v3, you can use the XCM hash as a sort of unique ID to identify an XCM.

Comment: Get the hash of the message directly? Is it unique when the message content is the same? Can you provide some sample code?